# How to write a transitive comparator when "equality" implies "order doesn't matter"?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, transitivity

I have a set of items that are serialized to a file. Some items can *rely* on other items, but circular references are not allowed. Thus, they need to be serialized in a way such that if `A` relies on `B`, `B` is serialized first in the file.

I wrote my `Comparator` that uses a `reliesOn()` function to determine if two items are linked:

```
Collections.sort(itemsToSort, new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item first, Item second) {
        boolean firstReliesOnSecond = reliesOn(first, second);
        if (firstReliesOnSecond) {
            return 1;
        }
        boolean secondReliesOnFirst = reliesOn(second, first);
        if (secondReliesOnFirst) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
});
```

This works for *some* cases, but not all. In debugging, it's obvious that the sort relies on the transitive nature of the `Comparator`, and understandably does not compare every possible pairing of items.

For example, with five items `A` through `E`, if:

```
A -> B
B -> E
C
D
E
```

Then one possible ordering would be:

```
E, B, A, C, D
```

At the very least, `E` comes before `B`, and `B` comes before `A`.

However, during the comparison phase (paraphrasing as an example), what happens is that `C` is compared to `E`, returning `0` because they have no relation. And then `C` is compared to `B`, and also returns `0`.

And as a result, the sorting algorithm assumes `B = E`, which is *not* the case. (Even though **I broke the `Comparator` contract**.) How can I write my `compare()` method in a way that ensures transitivity?

**Edit:** It was pointed out that I'm performing a topological sort on a directed acyclic graph. I'm having flashbacks to my Data Structures course. Fortunately Wikipedia seems to have a good linear-time algorithm for performing this sort - I'll give it a shot.

Comment: BTW, it's not `Comparator` that assumes B = E, it's the sorting algorithm. (`Comparator` contains very little code itself)

Comment: You're right - I suppose it's a combination of the sorting algorithm, and the contract that the `Comparator` is supposed to fulfill. I'll update my wording, thanks!

Comment: Can you access the related objects of an `Item`? Is there like a `getParents()` or something like that?

Comment: you can't use a sort. you have to go through the forest to get all the leaves first

Comment: @aioobe so vote to close as a duplicate?

Comment: Unless it's crystal clear I tend to be conservative with the close votes. In this case I'll leave it up to OP to decide if the answer in the other thread answers his question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I write my compare() method in a way that ensures transitivity?

As you've discovered the contract of a `Comparator` forces you to make a decision based on two given objects, while their relation in the overall sort may involve other objects.

What you have here is a DAG and what you're trying to do is a topological sort. The only way I see that it would be possible to do using a `Comparator` would be to first do a topological sort, and then using the indexes of the objects in this sorting as keys when implementing the comparator. But then of course there's no need for the comparator since you have already sorted the elements.

Comment: Thank you for this - you led me to the right place. (Will mark as answered when the time limit is up.)

Comment: Can you access the "parents" of each `Item`?

Comment: Yes, we have a visitor/utility method that will find them.

Comment: Then there may be a chance of solving it by checking if object 1 is found on the path from object 2 up to the root (or vice versa). But 1) it would just be a convoluted and suboptimal implementation of a topological sort and 2) you would need a way to resolve order of siblings

Answer (score 0):

Breaking the contract of `Comparator` does little to help you, since the standard sorting algorithms assume that you honor it.

Besides implementing a topological sort algorithm from Wikipedia you can also take a look at [this](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht) lib (which gets mentioned often when someone speaks of directed graphs and topological sorting) or [that](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=topological-sort) implementation.